# I can't make a C++ project, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

Earlier (even yesterday) I could make C++ projects, but now I have a strange problem. When I want to select empty project, the window with creating project settings disappears and shows again and I don't have any solution with any project. I have a blank area. The only thing I changed in this time is installing tools for Python and creating enviroment for interpreter. I can make Python or C# projects but can't make C++ projects. Maybe someone had the same problem?